# What is the best place to put pure and synchronous logic while using React with Redux and Redux-Saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

After previously using Redux-Thunk, I've been playing around with Redux-Saga lately. So far I am loving it for handling asynchronous tasks like network requests. So in using sagas, I will definitely put code with asynchronous logic into sagas. However, I'm a bit unsure where to put the rest of the synchronous logic. I'm debating whether I should leave them in the reducers or actions or create sagas for them as well.

Let's use a simple counter component in which a user is incrementing a count number state. This example is basic and doesn't have any async logic but am just using it to demonstrate my problem. In a real app I'd have both async and sync logic.

**Using Sagas for synchronous logic:**

1. Counter component dispatches `START_INCREMENT` action.
2. `START_INCREMENT` reducer case executes and just returns the old state.
3. Saga which was watching `START_INCREMENT` runs and `put`'s an `INCREMENT` action with a payload `incrementNumber`.
4. `INCREMENT` reducer case executes and takes the current state count and adds `incrementNumber` and returns the new state.

**Using Reducers to handle synchronous logic:**

1. Counter component dispatches `INCREMENT` action with `incrementNumber` payload.
2. `INCREMENT` reducer case executes and takes the current state count and adds `incrementNumber` and returns the new state.

**Using Actions to handle synchronous logic:**

1. Counter component dispatches `INCREMENT` action creator with `incrementNumber` as parameter.
2. Action creator returns action `INCREMENT` action with `count` payload. This is the updated count.
3. `INCREMENT` reducer case executes and takes the new count and replaces the count in the old state and returns the new state.

There's benefits and cons for me to each of these approaches. Listing a few:

**Sagas**

Pros

1. Logic is all in sagas and not scattered in a mix of sagas and actions/reducers.

Cons

1. More complex flow with 2 actions

**Reducers**

Pros

1. Very simple

Cons

1. Logic would be in 2 places, async logic in sagas and sync logic in reducers
2. Don't have access to other slices of state if it was needed
3. Reducers must be pure and we cannot use side effects, like Browser or DOM APIs

**Actions Creators**

Pros

1. Have access to others slices of state if needed using redux-thunk
2. Can put other side effect code in actions, like Browser or DOM APIs

Cons

1. Logic would be in 2 places, async logic in sagas and sync logic in actions
2. Harder to test

I'm leaning towards using Sagas for all async logic and actions creators for all sync logic and then keeping reducers lean. Does this approach make sense or is there a better way to handle synchronous logic in redux-saga?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as it's very simple I tend to leave the logic in my reducers, otherwise I like to have a file with utility methods that are called from my sagas. If you need some slice of state, you can pass it to the utility method as a parameter.